# What does “scaffold” mean in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am studying a guide in which scaffold is mentioned. I don't understand what it is.

Is it sort of built-in framework?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

see [rails guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding) for the explanation

> Rails scaffolding is a quick way to
>   generate some of the major pieces of
>   an application. If you want to create
>   the models, views, and controllers for
>   a new resource in a single operation,
>   scaffolding is the tool for the job.

Comment: I think the link may be outdated (as 'scaffold' / 'scaffolding' doesn't appear anywhere on the page) - has it moved?

Comment: @user5783745 perhaps but you find it here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Answer (score 12):

Scaffolding in Ruby on Rails refers to the auto generation of a simple set of a model, views and controller usually for a single table.

For example:

```
user@localhost$ ./scripts/generate scaffold users
```

Would create a full CRUD (create, read, update, delete) web interface for the Users table. Of course features like hashing the password, uploading images, etc... are not handled and must be added to the auto-generated code.

Answer (score 7):

In rails 3.2 when you type this in the TERMINAL, inside your rails app folder:

```
rails generate scaffold User
```

- the "User" part could be any name you choose...
- it creates all of the the structure for your CRUD (create, read, update, delete)
- in this creation it includes the controller, model, and views the views for each part of the CRUD (create, read, update, delete),
- and the code inside them to start you off with your CRUD (create, read, update, delete)
- its way easier to do this, instead of coding everything yourself, it saves you lots of time!

Answer (score 6):

I'm also studying Ruby On Rails, and here is how I remember it:

- Each scaffold is an object inside your application, that users will interact with. Users can create this object, update, read or delete it.
- At Facebook, one of these objects is *status*. Each user can create it, read, delete or update *status*.
- On Twitter, it's *tweet*.
- At Pinterest, it's *pins*.

Every application contains many such objects — statuses, photos, comments, users, etc.
You have to plan all of them and design future interactions between these objects and users of your application.

Answer (score 2):

Go through with links:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-scaffolding.htm

Comment: As of now, first link has no mention of scaffolding. Please follow https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/getting_started.html#getting-up-and-running-quickly-with-scaffolding

Answer (score 1):

lets have a simple example

we want to have an app with two data model one is user model with user_id,name and email and another is the post model with id and content.

we want to associate each post model with a particular user. we will accomplish this by recording the user_id of the owner of the post.

by using rails scaffolding command you can create rails scaffold command rails will generate the models and controller for the two data model.

you can save  a lot of time